# Regex to match all occurrences between comments and inside tag only (html)

Tags: php, regex

Regex `(preg_match_all())` should match **all** occurences of **Lorem** inside `<p></p>` tags located between `<!--COMMENT_begin-->` `<!--COMMENT_end-->` comments.

```
/<!--COMMENT_begin-->.*?(<p>.*?\bLorem\b.*?<\/p>).*?<!--COMMENT_end-->/sig
```

But this regex only matches the first occurence for the following markup.

```
<!--COMMENT_begin-->
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Lorem <span>Lorem</span></p>
<div>Lorem</div>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<!--COMMENT_end-->
```

Comment: Maybe `(?si)(?:\G(?!\A)|<!--COMMENT_begin-->)(?:(?!<!--COMMENT_(?:begin|end)-->).)*?\K<p>[^<]*\bLorem\b[^<]*<\/p>`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CQn4dz/1).

Comment: Unbelievable! Thx! The next step would be to replace all „Loren“ with „LoremXXX“ respecting this pattern. Is this possible using one preg_replace() statement??

Comment: Like in https://regex101.com/r/CQn4dz/2?

Comment: You are the best! Saved my week :)

Comment: Last addition: Need to replace several occurances of „Lorem“ inside a paragraph, too. Not only one. And this „Lorem“ or part might additionally be wrapped by `<span>` or similar.

Comment: Check `preg_replace_callback` then. It will be easier.

Comment: And just extending the last example to match each "Lorem" even if existing several times between the `<p>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(?si)(?:\G(?!\A)|(?:\G(?!\A)|<!--COMMENT_begin-->)(?:(?!<!--COMMENT_(?:begin|end)-->).)*?<p>)(?:(?!<\/?p>).)*?\K\bLorem\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/CQn4dz/4)

It will match all `Lorem` inside `p` tags that are located between `<!--COMMENT_begin-->` and `<!--COMMENT_end-->` in case insensitive mode.

Comment: Thx! But `\bLorem\b` should only be found if located between `<p></p>` tags. And inside one `<p></p>` possible several occurances of `Lorem` should match, too. Possible?

Comment: Wow, thats cool. Could this be extended using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to exclude "Lorem" from beeing inside an `a` tag or other like `<a[^>]*>.*?</a\s*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` or `[class|id]=".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. Or should this be realized as negations?

Comment: Your updated example also matches `<div>Lorem</div>`- but it shouldn't ;(

Comment: @JKB It does not match `<div>Lorem</div>` now. You may add SKIP-FAIL to your liking.

Comment: That is great! The SKIP FAIL must be put in front of all, right?

Comment: @JKB Yes, it makes sense more to put it first.